# Does Buddhism only reviewing the past and looking for the future? So, where is the "present"?

Tags: learning

To me, the “present” holds greater significance than both the past and the future. Why? Because the present is the canvas upon which I can actively wield influence. It’s where my actions ripple outward, shaping what awaits me in the days to come. And when this present moment eventually slips into the folds of history, it leaves behind valuable lessons—etched into memory—as I learn and grow from its tapestry of experiences.

Answer (score 1):

Buddhism's main theme is, **being in the present**. Which gives the **ability** / enough **concentration** to see the **truth**. (see/understand **four noble truths**.)

Buddha only speaks of the past, to let people know how other people walked the **path to Nirvana**.
Budda has only spoken about the future very little because it is less meaningful. (Only normal(us) misguided people think the future is the most important.)

Buddha only encourages us to be in the present, which is the only path to Nirvana.

**How to be at present?**

Buddha teaches how to be in the present all over the **Damma**. (Buddha's teachings.)
It's about concentration. It's about knowing what's going on in you, around you. (Not dreaming about the past and future.)
You can practice **Samatha meditation** to get absolute concentration.
(This is not the true purpose of Buddha's teaching.)

Now, One should use this concentration/ability to be in the present to understand the **Four Noble Truths**(Nirvana).

Which is **vipassana meditation** (The process of using concentration to understand the Four Noble Truths).

Which is the **main goal of Buddhism**.

Answer (score 0):

Buddha teaches us to stay in the present.

"What is past is left behind.
The future is as yet unreached.
Whatever quality is present
you clearly see right there,
right there."

- Buddha
- From the Bhaddekaratta Sutta